# Extracting and listing set of values using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement where I have got to extract and list ids from different hierarchies. Below is the sample XML: (I have provided 3 level hierarchy to reflect the complexion)

**Input XML:**

```
<Wrapper>
    <A Id="A@1">
        <B Id="B#1">
            <C Id="C$1"/>
            <C Id="C$2"/>
        </B>
        <B Id="B#2">
            <C Id="C$3"/>
            <C Id="C$4"/>
        </B>
        <B Id="B#3">
            <C Id="C$5"/>
            <C Id="C$6"/>
        </B>
        <B Id="B#4>
            <C Id="C$7"/>
            <C Id="C$8"/>
        </B>
    </A>
</Wrapper>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
A Ids:
A@1

B Ids:
B#1
B#2
B#3
B#4

C Ids:
C$1
C$2
C$3
C$4
C$5
C$6
C$7
C$8
```

**Input XSL:** The principle is simple: I encounter root element "\" write the text and for-each hierarchy I provide **absolute XPath**  and access Id .. here goes the code:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#10;'"/>  

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <!--List of A Ids-->
      <xsl:text>A Ids:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="/Wrapper/A/@Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,$linefeed)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>


    <!--List of B Ids-->
      <xsl:text>B Ids:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="/Wrapper/A/B/@Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,$linefeed)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

    <!--List of C Ids-->
      <xsl:text>C Ids:</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="/Wrapper/A/B/C/@Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,$linefeed)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>


  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Is there a better way??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is based on grouping elements by their name, not by the position which they are occupying in the hierarchy. So this solution would output the sam even when

- The nodes are not grouped by name as they are, e.g. C elements could be at the root of A elements instead of being children of B elements.
- When you add nodes with different than A, B, C anywhere in the hierarchy (however, they have to be children of Wrapper) their @Ids are going to be automatically listed by the XSLT stylesheet.

If you want a general solution based on the position of the node in the document instead of using their name to group them, then tell me and I will try to adapt the solution. Meanwhile this is my solution based in 'Muenchian Grouping'

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#10;'"/>  

    <!-- Use key to group elements by local-name -->
    <xsl:key name="name-key" match="/Wrapper//*" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="Wrapper">
        <!-- Obtain the first element for each group, where a group is
             the set of elements sharing a name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('name-key', local-name())[1])]">
            <!-- Print header -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ' Ids:', $linefeed)" />
            <!-- Obtain all the nodes (children of Wrapper) with the local-name of
                 the current node using the previous key -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('name-key', local-name())" />
            <!-- Print line feed at the end of each different group -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Print the information for each element -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Id" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was thinking to use Key/generate-id() feature but couldn't really get hold of it.. now it shows the usage. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad you found my solution helpful. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#10;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--List of A Ids-->
        <xsl:text>A Ids:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//A" />

        <!--List of B Ids-->
        <xsl:text>B Ids:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//B" />

        <!--List of C Ids-->
        <xsl:text>C Ids:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//C" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Id" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```